# CDI @Specializes and Constructor Injection with @Postconstruct

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, cdi, postconstruct

I have the following classes:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BaseClass {
    private SomeDependency dep;

    public BaseClass(){}

    @Inject
    public BaseClass(SomeDependency dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
        dep.doSomething(); // Point "A"
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return "BaseClass-Property";
}

@Specializes
public class SpecialClass extends BaseClass() {

    @Override
    public String getProperty() {
        return "SpecialClass-Property";
    }
}
```

Now in some .xhtml I have something like

```
<h:outputText value="#{baseClass.property}" />
```

This works fine without the `SpecialClass`. It breaks with a `NullPointerException` at Point "A" if I include the `SpecialClass` in the project.

Well, according [to the Weld specification](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-2.2/en-US/html_single/#_using_specialization), this is more or less intended behavior:

> When an enabled bean specializes another bean, the other bean is never
>   instantiated or called by the container.

Nevertheless, now I have to make sure that every `@Specializes` bean implements the complete constructor like

```
public SpecialClass() {}

@Inject
public SpecialClass(SomeDependency dep) { super(dep); }
```

which IMHO is kind of counter-intuitive and produces a lot of duplicated, boilerplate code, especially with something like 5-6 arguments for every constructor. Also, this is never caught when creating a new specialized bean since the project is always still compile clean.

Am I doing something wrong or is there no alternative to implementing the constructors over and over again?

BTW, I do use Constructor Injection to create easily testable classes where I can just use the constructor to "Inject" dummy implementations of the dependencies.

Comment: Surely, even default raw java instantiation will fail. Constructors are not inherited, save for the default no-arg constructor.

Comment: Well, I know about the "raw" instantiation, I had hoped that the CDI logic takes away that burden from me as a programmer ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

CDI 1.1 spec at section 4.3 says:

> "The only way one bean can completely override a second bean at all
>   injection points is if it implements all the bean types and declares
>   all the qualifiers of the second bean."

Your base class is annotated with the Named qualifier and the specializing class is not. You should also mark it with Alternative and enable it in beans.xml. There's also the ViewScoped annotation. Unless it's the Omnifaces' ViewScoped, it looks like you're mixing up JSF managed beans with CDI beans.

Comment: HInt: OmniFaces @ViewScoped throws an exception if bean doesn't implement Serializable.

Comment: It is OmniFaces ViewScoped since I am on JEE6 / CDI 1.0, but 1.0 declares the same specification in that paragraph. The specialized bean is used in that project, all works fine, I was only going at that Inject-constructor logic which I had hoped would be handled in an easier way ...